# Check if input date not between date1 and date2 in first row to last row plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a procedure to insert a new start_date into my table but i want it not between date1 and date2 in first row to last row. it mean i want to compare then new insert date from first row to to last row if it is not between then insert in into table. how can i check that, please anyone know tell me.

my table name is `resister`

and this is my table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the `NOT EXISTS` as following:

```
SELECT &&NEW_INPUT_DATE
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 
       FROM RESISTER
      WHERE &&NEW_INPUT_DATE BETWEEN START_DATE AND END_DATE)
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

As I see it from data next date range always continues the previous. So you might just check if the new start_date is greater that max(end_date). Like this

```
create or replace procedure insert_date(p_start_date date, p_end_date date)
is
  l_min_date date;
  l_max_date date;
begin
  select min(start_date), max(end_date) 
    into l_min_date, l_max_date
    from registers;

  if (p_start_date > l_max_date) and (p_end_date > p_start_date) then
    insert into registers(start_date, end_date) values(p_start_date, p_end_date);
  end if;
end;
```

If it is possible for the user to enter a date prov the past (e.g. 01/01/1980 - 31/01/1980) then the "if" clause would be looking similar to this

```
... if (p_start_date > l_max_date or p_end_date < l_min_date) and (p_end_date > p_start_date) then ...
```